# how can I set the dynamic dialog from a bean in JSF

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-dialog-framework

I'm opening dialog from a backing bean like this:

```
Map options = new HashMap(); options.put("resizable", true); options.put("width", 1400); options.put("contentWidth", "100%"); options.put("height", 800);
options.put("minimizable", true);
options.put("maximizable", true);

PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("pageName", options, null);
```

How can I set the dialog id?

I tried to put it like an option, but it didn't help:

```
options.put("id", "someId");
```

My Primefaces version is 6.2

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
```

Also check this: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/primefaces/programmatic-dialog.html